# Files in Samba share not visible on some Windows computers (but on others they are)

Tags: linux, windows, debian, network-shares, samba

I have a Debian 8 Linux machine with Samba 2.4. On this machine I have configured a Samba share:

```
[myshare]
path = /path/to/my/share
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
public = yes
force user = myuser
```

I can add this share on any Windows 7 and 8 computer in my network (as a drive and as a folder, by using `\\[linux_ip]\myshare`) and open the folders within it. This works without problems.

However, on *some* Windows computers the files within *some* of the folders in this share are not shown at all, they appear as empty. But on most Windows systems it works perfectly fine, they instantly react to changes on the Linux share (Explorer view instantly updates size, dates and filenames).

Due to this behaviour I suspect the problem to be on the Windows side, not on the Linux side.

What settings could I try to make all the Windows machines display the share contents correctly?

Comment: Are they the same folders/files across multiple machines? Or could you have a state where two machines can see different things?

Comment: @tanantish I don't really get your question. All Windows computers access `\\[linux_ip]\myshare`, which is a folder (with subfolders) on a single Linux machine. In an ideal world all Windows machines should always see the same. In my world however, only most Windows machines see the same, some machines can't see the whole content of some subfolders (but of other subfolders they can). So, on these particular Windows machines some subfolders of the share either appear perfectly fine (up to date, complete) or completely empty (which is the problem).

Comment: It's more for clarification - you said *some* machines and *some* folders but I can't tell if it's the same set of folders but on various machines or if it's different for each machine. When debugging, esp remotely, we don't have the advantage of seeing what's on your terminals so it's harder to make sensible assumptions.